# How to setup a bitbake/Yocto recipe to use only a subset of the boost library?

Tags: boost, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am playing a bit around with my Raspberry Pi and Yocto. I wrote a program. This is build with cmake and links against some parts of the boost library.

To keep the sd-card memory food print as small as possible I like to tell yocto, that it has only to link/build & deploy against some certain parts of the the boost library. My problem I do not know how to do this. Maybe someone can tell me.

Below I put the listing of my recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "mytest"
SECTION = "app"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit cmake

DEPENDS = "boost libconfig"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

SRC_URI = "git:///home/mytest/;protocol=file"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

I am only using from boost:

```
system thread program_options
```

As far as I see Yocto is building separate packages for the libs - like

> libboost-thread1.66.0-1.66.0-r0.cortexa7hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm

The source of the [boost recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-support/boost/) does not tell how to include the parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following instructions to your recipe:

```
DEPENDS = "boost libconfig"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "boost-system boost-thread boost-program-options"
```

And it will ship only requested libs.

Comment: it does not work: ERROR: Required build target 'rpi-basic-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['rpi-basic-image', 'mytest', 'libboost-system']

Comment: Did you try to add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libboost-system libboost-thread libboost-program_options"` to `local.conf` ?

Comment: when using `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkgs -p boost`, it seems packages don't have `lib` prefix, can you try `RDEPENDS_${PN} = "boost-system boost-thread boost-program_options"` ?

Comment: thanks for the hint with oe-pkgdata-util. The changes generating the same error as above.

Comment: you don't mix DEPENDS/RDEPENDS aren't you? (see edit)

Comment: be shure I done it in the same way as you described.

Comment: I edited answer from `boost-program_options` to `boost-program-options` as it was not working